# Synonym for "greet", but in a somber way

Tags: word-choice

Sentence usage:

> I open the door and walk inside, and the unfortunately familiar brown walls and the smooth tiled floors greet me.

I want to have a sad and depressing tone to that sentence, so "greet" is not appropriate.

What would be an appropriate word to replace "greet" to keep that somber feeling?

Comment: But *greet* doesn't necessarily have any positive connotation, so I'm not sure that you necessarily need another word.  One of the examples for *greet* at Merriam-Webster is ["greeted him with boos"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greet)

Comment: @stangdon good point.

Comment: I don't think you can express this somberness of greeting with a verb alone. You might consider simply shifting the word "unfortunately" to be directly before **greet**: ".... and the familiar brown walls and smooth tiled floors unfortunately greet me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be:

> acknowledge - show that one has noticed or recognized (someone) by
>   making a gesture or greeting.

Used on its own, it does not carry any connotation of warmth in the greeting.